# How to fix invalid arguments error using R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Trying to create a histogram that will take in what stat the user would like and what position that player plays in.

UI entry

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("NFL Combine players"),
  selectInput(inputId = "num", label = "Choose a Stat",
              choices = c("Ht", "Wt", "Vertical", "forty", "BenchReps", "Cone", "BroadJump", "Shuttle")),
  selectInput(inputId = "pos", label = "Player Positions",
              choices = c("C", "CB", "DB", "DE", "DT", "EDGE", "FB", "FS", "G", "ILB", "K", "LB", "LS", "NT", "OG", "OL", "OLB", "OT", "P", "QB", "RB", "S", "SS", "TE", "WR")),
  plotOutput("hist", click = "plot_click")
)
```

Server Entry

```r
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$hist = renderPlot({
    hist(rnorm(input$num, input$pos))
  })
}
```

I expect the output to be a reactive histogram that will change when players positions or stats have been changed

Comment: Please edit your code and apply code bracket correctly.

Comment: Your app has no data. Where do you expect to get the data for the histogram?

Comment: The `rnorm` function is for generating random normally-distributed data, based on a count (`n`, the first argument) and two parameters: `mean=` and `sd=` (both with defaults). You are feeding that function two arguments, which will be interpreted as `n` and `mean=`, but they are both `character`. Does `rnorm("Ht", "DB")` work on the console? I suspect you have a `data.frame` (I'll call it `x`), and what you really want is something like `dat <- x$val[ x$stat == input$num & x$pos == input$pos]`, then `hist(rnorm(1000, mean=dat))`. (I'm wrong, I know, but how close am I?)

Comment: user11405911, if you happen to come back and read this ... please don't (1) ask a question, (2) be unresponsive to constructive requests to improve it, and then (3) delete the account without giving *any kind of thanks, feedback, or acknowledgement*. It's really just inconsiderate/rude.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your input variables are strings while rnorm takes numeric arguments.

You can see how it works if you use 1 as input variables and cast this to numeric at the server side.

Now if you change the value in the input box the error 'invalid arguments' will appear again. This is because you will have the same problem as before where you try to give a character as argument for rnorm.

Run the example below to see it for yourself.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("NFL Combine players"), selectInput(inputId = "num", 
label = "Choose a Stat", choices = c("1", "Wt", "Vertical", "forty", "BenchReps", 
"Cone", "BroadJump", "Shuttle")),

           selectInput(inputId = "pos", label = "Player Positions", selected = 5,
                       choices = c("1", "CB", "DB", "DE", "DT", "EDGE", "FB", "FS", "G", "ILB", "K", "LB", "LS", "NT", "OG", "OL", "OLB", "OT", "P", "QB", "RB", "S", "SS", "TE", "WR")),
           plotOutput("hist", click = "plot_click")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$hist = renderPlot({
        hist(rnorm(as.numeric(input$num), as.numeric(input$pos)))
    })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I know the question is under-informed (no data), but `as.numeric("forty")` and `as.numeric("CB")` seem ridiculous (they are both very likely to produce `NA`).

Comment: @r2evans Yes that is true. But it does clearly demonstrate the difference between his first example and why it does not work and how using a num does make work.

This is purely because I don't have any data and this way he can at least experiment with what does an doesn't work.

Comment: I guess he got his answer, accepted the answer but then deleted his account. So I don't get the reputation. @r2evans you seem more experienced here, does that happen more often? 

I finally had a question I could answer and get some reputation to be able to upvote answers.

Comment: I don't see many people immediately delete their account; it annoys me a little, but this is a free digital-society so nothing can be done to prevent it. This might partially feed the reputation-paranoia of answering a question from a user who has never accepted a reasonable answer, more so for first-time askers who have been members for hours or days.